# Deploy Node JS application in Weblogic

Tags: node.js, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have created a node application as a rest service and trying to deploy it on Weblogic but didn't find any way to deploy it. I have added the META_INF & WEB-INF but don't know what to add in the weblogic.xml file. Please suggest what should I do!

Below is the code of the weblogic.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
 <context-root>/</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 3):

A Node.JS backend application is written in Javascript.

**Weblogic is a JEE Container** and so you **can't** deploy a Node.JS application to Weblogic.

Comment: Is there any way to configure the reverse proxy in weblogic to point the nodejs web application?

Comment: There is no reverse proxy in WebLogic... Use Apache or HAProxy or nginx.